# How do I insert a picture into the top of a page a word document without leaving blank spaces?

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to insert pictures into a word document to be on the TOP of the inserted page.
If I choose "Top Center" or "Top Right/Left", the complete paragraph from the proceeding text jumps to be AFTER the picture, even if it 5+ lines, leaving a BIG empty blank space in the previous page.
If I choose, "In line with text", it looks good, BUT with a single line being proceeding the picture on the top of the inserted page.

I want the layout to be so that a picture be at the top of the page while the proceeding and following text stays fluid, without leaving blanks in between.
Furthermore, how can I move that inserted picture pixel by pixel using the arrows?

PLEASE HELP! It is getting REALLY frustrating, I have around 35 pictures...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must set the top margin to 0cm.
(double click the blank space or open page settings)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Setting the top margin to 0cm didn't fix the problem. However, double clicking the empty space seemed to fill it with text. But, I cannot edit THAT text properly, such as backspacing or whatever.

Comment: Perhaps you should place it into the header as an alternate solution. Or on the Image (Picture?) tab you should change its behavior to behave as a character or anchor. Anchors can be moved anywhere, characters also, if you have set margin to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use text warpping, choose `behind text` for around a picture.

[image: Text Wrapping]

Or right click the picture, select text wrapping then select behind text. if u want to move the picture around perfect, just right click, text wrapping, then select tight.

see [screenshoot](http://i.cubeupload.com/bvQ1uh.png)

Comment: Behind text, completely hides the text behind the picture.

Comment: no, text warpping `behind text` will to move the picture behind text, and you could to move the picture around perfect

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this. What I did was insert the image, open "Format Picture" properties, select the "Picture tab" and use the 'Crop from' option to make the area of the picture larger from the bottom (using i.e. -6) which added white space at the bottom, those moving the image to the top of the page. Not great, but it worked.